# Solidity: reserved words as variables, labels, or function names

Tags: solidity

In JavaScript you cannot use the reserved words as variables, labels, or function names. Does Solidity have the same restrictions?

I'm wondering about the following example from the Solidity documentation:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;

contract Coin {
    // The keyword "public" makes those variables
    // readable from outside.
    address public minter;
    mapping (address => uint) public balances;

    // Events allow light clients to react on
    // changes efficiently.
    event Sent(address from, address to, uint amount);

    // This is the constructor whose code is
    // run only when the contract is created.
    function Coin() {
        minter = msg.sender;
    }

    function mint(address receiver, uint amount) {
        if (msg.sender != minter) return;
        balances[receiver] += amount;
    }

    function send(address receiver, uint amount) {
        if (balances[msg.sender] < amount) return;
        balances[msg.sender] -= amount;
        balances[receiver] += amount;
        Sent(msg.sender, receiver, amount);
    }
}
```

But `from` is a reserved word, used in `ImportDirective`:

```
ImportDirective = 'import' StringLiteral ('as' Identifier)? ';'
        | 'import' ('*' | Identifier) ('as' Identifier)? 'from' StringLiteral ';'
        | 'import' '{' Identifier ('as' Identifier)? ( ',' Identifier ('as' Identifier)? )* '}' 'from' StringLiteral ';'
```

Answer (score 2):

to get the list of the reserved words look at the grammar.txt file or this [one](https://github.com/webdaford/smart-contract-tools/blob/master/workspace/com.dell.research.bc.eth.solidity.editor/src/com/dell/research/bc/eth/solidity/editor/Solidity.xtext). the keyword **From** alone is not a reserved word because it is defined into the import context (expression). 
in your example

```
ImportDirective = 'import' StringLiteral ('as' Identifier)? ';'
        | 'import' ('*' | Identifier) ('as' Identifier)? 'from' StringLiteral ';'
        | 'import' '{' Identifier ('as' Identifier)? ( ',' Identifier ('as' Identifier)? )* '}' 'from' StringLiteral ';'
```

import  is a reserved word but from isn't.

Comment: Please update link: https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/blob/develop/docs/grammar.txt

Answer (score 0):

The list of reserved keywords, which are included in testing for what should receive the error `Expected identifier but got reserved keyword`, is [here](https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/blob/develop/test/libsolidity/SolidityParser.cpp#L489).  The list of reserved tokens checked by the parser is in [Tokens.h](https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/blob/develop/libsolidity/parsing/Token.h#L225).  The official documentation about reserved words is [here](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/miscellaneous.html#reserved-keywords).

[As of](https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/blob/b1ab81ef22030ee16c6d216bfe6a4dc74b726985/test/libsolidity/SolidityParser.cpp#L489) [this answer](https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/blob/aaa50189a90ba2e5ebd2b11fc601fecf61ffca22/libsolidity/parsing/Token.h#L225), the [list](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.5.0/miscellaneous.html#reserved-keywords) is:

> "abstract", "after", "alias", "apply", "auto", "case", "catch", "copyof", "default", "define", "final", "immutable", "implements", "in", "inline", "let", "macro", "match", "mutable", "null", "of", "override", "partial", "promise", "reference", "relocatable", "sealed", "sizeof", "static", "supports", "switch", "try", "type", "typedef", "typeof", "unchecked"